# Clicking a button highlights the while vertical stack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xetrbmnszjc tutorial to learn SwiftUI. In a view, we have a vertical stack, which has some text and a button at the bottom. When I click the button, the whole of the vertical stack view is highlighted. I cannot understand why this happens.

```
    VStack {
            Text(drink.description)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .font(.body)
            .lineLimit(nil)
                .lineSpacing(12)
            
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                OrderButton()
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.top,25)
        }.padding(.top)
            .padding(.bottom)
    }

struct OrderButton: View{
    var body: some View{
        Button(action:{}){
            Text("Order Now")
        }.frame(width:200,height:50)
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

[image]

Please help on how to fix it. Since SwiftUI is relatively new, it becomes difficult to find answers to problems.

The attached image shows the scenario when I click on the `Order Now` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Button(action:{}){
                Text("Order Now")
                  .frame(width:200,height:50)
                  .font(.headline)
                  .foregroundColor(.white)
                  .background(Color.black)
            }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
             .cornerRadius(10)
```

You need to change view inside button, not frame itself. View which you put in there sets frame to all button automatically, and clickable plane also be the same frame as view.

Comment: That works! Also, if there is some elaboration that can be made on "why" does this work, could you please do that. That will be helpful to make concepts clearer and help future users as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure that will be really helpful :)